# Sort MultiDimensional Array by Number Value with Zero Last

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

What I'm trying to do is sort a multidimensional array by a number but have any values equal to 0, to be at the end of the array.

This code works for sorting with 0's and single digits, but it seems to break when different numbers are added to it.

The output needs to be:
41,42,43,44,45,46,0,0,0

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        "position" => 41,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 43,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 42,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 44,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 45,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 0,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 0,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 0,
    ),
    array(
        "position" => 46,
    ),
);
// Sort ascending 
usort($array, 'sortByPosition');

// Show result
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

function sortByPosition($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] != 0 ? $a['position'] - $b['position'] : $b['position'] - $a['position'];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comparison function is a bit off. I would do it like this:

```
function sortByPosition($a, $b) {
    if ($a['position'] == $b['position']) return 0;
    if ($a['position'] == 0) return 1;
    if ($b['position'] == 0) return -1;
    return $a['position'] > $b['position'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

- First, if both positions are the same, return 0, regardless of
  whether either of them are zero.
- Second and third, if either of them *are* zero, that one should sort
  after the other (since it already would have returned if they were
  both zero).
- Fourth, neither are zero, so just compare the values normally.

Comment: Ok this makes sense now. Thanks for the answer. Looks like there's another answer that works as well.

Comment: The other one is simpler. No worries if you'd rather accept it.

Comment: For people trying to figure out the same thing I was, I think your answer gives the explanation, which I believe is more important.

Comment: Regarding the comment on the other answer, if non-numeric values (false, null, etc.) also need to be considered, `===` should be used here rather than `==`, or those values would be sorted to the end after the zeros.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's what I mean. If value can be `null`, I'd rather use `is_null` (instead of `!`). If the question is about `0`, the check should be `0`. Who can guarantee, there won't be `null` as a `position`? I prefer your answer because it is easier to understand at 2am when the system is down and you need to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { 
    if (!$a['position']) return 1;
    if (!$b['position']) return -1;
    return $a['position']-$b['position'];
});
```

Comment: What if `$a['position']` is false or null or empty array at all? The question was about `0`.

Comment: This is also a correct answer and it works in my case with numbers, however, watch out for false values. See accepted answer for explanation of how this sorting works.

Comment: @Axalix: The array contains only numbers, your question is irrelevant.